# bootstrap modal not resize when ajax loaded inside

Tags: scroll, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal. after it's shown, I run the ajax to get remote content. after ajax get success. Response shown but bootstrap modal not allow me to scroll. I've already search for resolution but nothing. Help me please!

JS:

```
$("#episodenext").modal('show');
$("#episodenext").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
    $(this).find(".modal-body").load('/content.php');
});
```

[image: Screenshot with the problem]

Comment: maybe this is history error that no one can fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this work by setting the `.modal-body` height to be 70% of the document height before it loads the page `content.php`.

**Try this code here**

```
$("#episodenext .modal-body").css({
    'overflow': 'auto',
    'height': $(document).height() * 0.7
});
$("#episodenext").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
    $(this).find(".modal-body").load('/content.php');
});
$("#episodenext").modal('show');
```

And you can check my example here: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/bootstrap-modalscroll/

**UPDATE**

Here is the screen capture with the modal after applying 70% height:

[image: Bootstrap Modal Custom Body Height]

Comment: I found a solution by using `$('#myModal').data('bs.modal').handleUpdate() ` but I don't know where to put it in.

Comment: Did you try my solution? Where did you find that solution with the `handleUpdate`? Can you provide a link?

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15106 and http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/

Comment: I tried this and it does not seem to work for your case, or maybe there is something I am missing. I think it's more easy to set a percentage `.modal-body` height related to the page document height like I use in my example. Did you try my method?

Comment: Please check the screen capture at my updated answer. Isn't that you want to achieve?

Comment: Can you make the window scroll instead of that div ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Can you provide a page with such an example? If you want the scroll bars to be in page, then you'll have the modal dialog expand beyond the page height like this example here http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/bootstrap-modalscroll/window-scroll.html. If you want the dialog to have a smallest height than the page height, then the scroll bars need to be at the `.modal-body`.